# The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this' with typescript

Tags: react-native

I am converting my JavaScript code to Typescript. Before I had a builder but now he is returning this error to me and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Here is my file screen.tsx

Error:

"The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'"

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    //----My styles----
});


const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
    const { signed, signIn, user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    console.log(signed);
    console.log(user);

    function handleSign() {
        signIn();
    }
    

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainer={{ flex: 1 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_header}>Sign in</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text_header_bottom}>Enter</Text>
                </View>

                <Animatable.View
                    animation="fadeInUpBig"
                    style={styles.footer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_footer}>User</Text>
                        <View style={styles.action}>
                            <FontAwesome
                                name="user-o"
                                color="#000"
                                size={20} />
                            <TextInput
                                placeholder="username"
                                style={styles.textInput}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.textInputChange(text)}
                            />
                            {this.state.check_textInputChange ?
                                <Animatable.View
                                    animation="bounceIn">
                                    <Feather
                                        name="check-circle"
                                        color="green"
                                        size={20}
                                    />
                                </Animatable.View>
                                : null}
                        </View>
                        
                </Animatable.View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Could I check your full class code? I can't understand what is problem on this code

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

> In Functional Component, There is no `this`. At Functional Component `this` is global this

### Answer

In `Class Component` there is this, But `Functional Component` hasn't this.
**You can search different between both.**

I mean this <- is class componeny syntax and if you use it in Functional Component this mean global this(like `global` in node, `window` in browser).

In javascript there is no type error checker, So you can't see this error. But in typescript there is type checker. So type checker occur `this` in `Functional Component` is unsuitable

And if you want to use state in functional component, just use `useState`

### Example

```js
const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
    const { signed, signIn, user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [state, setState] = useState(SomeState)              //  <- here!

    function handleSign() {
        signIn();
    }
    

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainer={{ flex: 1 }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_header}>Sign in</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text_header_bottom}>Enter</Text>
                </View>

                <Animatable.View
                    animation="fadeInUpBig"
                    style={styles.footer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text_footer}>User</Text>
                        <View style={styles.action}>
                            <FontAwesome
                                name="user-o"
                                color="#000"
                                size={20} />
                            <TextInput
                                placeholder="username"
                                style={styles.textInput}
                                onChangeText={(text) => this.textInputChange(text)}
                            />
                            {state.check_textInputChange ?         // <- here
                                <Animatable.View
                                    animation="bounceIn">
                                    <Feather
                                        name="check-circle"
                                        color="green"
                                        size={20}
                                    />
                                </Animatable.View>
                                : null}
                        </View>
                        
                </Animatable.View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default SignIn;
```

### Reference

1. [About this in javascript - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
2. [About Functional and Class Component - React Document](https://ko.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Sorry, Could you explain your solution better? Please

Comment: Oh I see :) I hope I helpful to you

Comment: What do you mean with SomeState? in mine it returns an error

Comment: some state is state. I think you need to study what is `state` and what is `state`

Comment: And some state can be what ever you want to use